# Php Array Post Error

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I have an array with 1200 records, But when I submit the form the code counts 250 records in the array. Why?

This is the code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['ok'])) {
    echo count($_POST['precios']);
    // showme only 250 récords
}
?>
<form method='POST' action='productos.php'>
    <button class="btn green"  type="submit" name="ok"> Actualizar de forma masiva</button>
    <?php
    $query4334x = "select * from Productos";

    $result_categorias4334x = mysql_db_query($dbname, $query4334x)
        or die("Failed Query of " . $query4334x);  //guardo en una variable los registros obtenidos con el query

    $numero5 = mysql_num_rows($result_categorias4334x);
    echo $numero5;
    // showme 1200 récords

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_categorias4334x)) {
        $precio = $row['Precio'];
        ?>
        <input type="text" name="precios[]" value="<?php echo $precio; ?>">
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</form>
```

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated mysql_ code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using mysqli or PDO as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: thanks for the information. i Will se the bobby-tables.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change settings in your php.ini `max_input_vars` and `post_max_size`

Try Something like below which works for me

`implode()` the array into one long string and `explode()` it on the server side.

`json_encode()` could probably work as well.

Example:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_categorias4334x)) {
        $precio[] = $row['Precio'];
    }
<input type="text" name="precios" value="<?php echo implode(",",$precio); ?>">
```

//POST

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['ok'])) {
    $precios = $_POST['precios'];
    $preciosarr = explode(",", $precios);
    print_r($preciosarr);
}
?>
```

**NOTE: The maximum number of characters allowed in the  element. Default value is 524288**

Comment: thanks! but i need one input for récord to refresh the prices. the code showme only one input

Comment: Perfect! works! but i have a problem.
The user has to modify the input with the value (price) he wants for each record. This way I have only one input.

The original code is:
   
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_categorias4334)){
      $precio = $row['Precio'];

<input type="text" name="precio[]" value="<?php echo $precio; ?>">

 }

Comment: can soy help me @AhmedGinani?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to update following settings in your php.ini

**max_input_vars = 1500**

**post_max_size  = 64M**

You just adjust both the variable according to your needs.

Comment: my server doesn't allow me to change the php.ini. other solution?

Comment: Can you confirm are you able to use ini_set ? 

ini_set('max_input_vars',1500);
ini_set('post_max_size','64M');

Comment: This settings are not changeable in runtime, they are applied before script is executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have access to php.ini you can try setting them in .htaccess

```
php_value  max_input_vars  1500   
php_value  post_max_size   64M
```

Answer (score -2):

If this is part of a loop, you need to index the array

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['precios']); $i++) { ?>
    ...
    <input type="text" name="precios[]" value="<?php echo $precio; ?>">
    ...
    <?php
}
```

also check this instead of echo use **print_r()** or **var_dump()**

```
print_r( count($_POST['precios']));
```

Comment: how would looping through POST variables help? User wants to display data from DB, but then posted back value is too small. You also haven't defined $precio.